# Avoid pushing full path

Tags: git

I tried creating an empty repo in Github and push my existing local repo into Github. For some reason after pushing the local repo, when I look in Github, a bunch of directories had been created.
Eg: `/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/MyRepo`

I just want to push the files in MyRepo without creating the folders. How would I go about doing so?

Commands used:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/MyRepo.git
```

cd to the directory with files

```
git add *.h
git add *.cpp
git commit -m "Commit"
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: How exactly did you do this - the exact command would be useful

Comment: What is the output of `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that I did not do `git init`.